# Junit Code coverage for SocketTimeout exception inside ResourceAccessException

Tags: java, junit, mockito

My goal is to get code coverage for my Adapter class. I have written Junit test case for read SocketTimeoutException(read timed out), it is not calling getSampleStatus() method. How to call this getSampleStatus() from my Test class.

```
rest class:
===========

    class MyAdapter
    {

        @Autowired
        BDSRequestForSubmitGIApp bdsRequestForSubmitGIApp;

        @Autowired
        RestTemplate restTemplate;


          public BDSSubmitResponse submitGIApplicationToBDS(String channelId,String customerId,String cinSuffix, String countryCode) throws CrossSellOffersException {
            BDSSubmitResponse bdsSubmitResponse = null;
            try {

                bdsSubmitResponse = restTemplate.postForObject(env.getProperty("bds_submit_gi_url"),
                        bdsRequestForSubmitGIApp, BDSSubmitResponse.class);

            } catch (ResourceAccessException e) {
                if (e.getCause().getClass().equals(SocketTimeoutException.class)) {
                    retrun getSampleStatus();// Junit is not covering this line
                } else {
                    throw new CrossSellOffersException("DOMAIN_CONNECT_FAILURE",
                            "Couldn’t contact domain sub-system(s). Please try after some time.");
                }
            }
            return bdsSubmitResponse;
          }

          private BDSSubmitResponse getSampleStatus(){
          //business logic
          }
    }


Junit :
=======

    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    class MyAdapterTest
    {
        @InjectMocks
        private MyAdapter crossSellOffersBDSAdapter;

        @Mock
        private RestTemplate restTemplate;

        @Mock
        BDSRequestForSubmitGIApp bdsRequestForSubmitGIApp;

        @Test
        public void submitGIApplicationToBDSReadTimeoutTest() throws Exception {
            final String ERROR_MESSAGE =
                    "I/O error on POST request for \"https://message-publisher.uat.apps.cs.sgp.dbs.com/message\": Read timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out";
            Mockito.when(env.getProperty("bds_submit_gi_url")).thenReturn("https://message-publisher.uat.apps.cs.sgp.dbs.com/message");
            Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForObject(env.getProperty("bds_submit_gi_url"),
                bdsRequestForSubmitGIApp, BDSSubmitResponse.class)).thenThrow(new ResourceAccessException(ERROR_MESSAGE));

            BDSSubmitResponse response = crossSellOffersBDSAdapter.submitGIApplicationToBDS(requestBody, "MBSG",  "S9718016D", "00");
        }
    }
```

How to get code coverage for getSampleStatus() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ResourceAccessException class present in org.springframework.web.client package and its constructors are
**ResourceAccessException(String msg)
ResourceAccessException(String msg, IOException ex)**

the below test case will work for ResourceAccessException

```
@Test(expected = CrossSellOffersFulFilmentException.class)
    public void submitGIApplicationToBDSExceptionTest() throws Exception {
        //Given
        final String ERROR_MESSAGE = "ResourceAccessException";
        IOException exception = new IOException("IO exception");

        //When
        Mockito.when(env.getProperty("bds_submit_gi_url")).thenReturn("https://message-publisher.uat.apps.cs.sgp.dbs.com/message");
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForObject(env.getProperty("bds_submit_gi_url"),
                bdsRequestForSubmitGIApp, BDSSubmitResponse.class)).thenThrow(new ResourceAccessException(ERROR_MESSAGE, exception));

        //Then
        crossSellOffersBDSAdapter.submitGIApplicationToBDS(requestBody, "MBSG", "S9718016D", "00");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have your mock throw a SocketTimeoutException instead!

```
when(restTemplate.postForObject(
  env.getProperty("bds_submit_gi_url"),
  bdsRequestForSubmitGIApp,
  BDSSubmitResponse.class)
).thenThrow(new SocketTimeoutException(ERROR_MESSAGE));
```

Comment: If i use SocketTimeoutException in rest template,
I am getting below exception and it is not covering getSampleStatus() method.
=====
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Checked exception is invalid for this method!
Invalid: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: I/O error on POST request for "https://message-publisher.uat.apps.cs.sgp.dbs.com/message": Read timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
 at com.dbs.crossselloffers.adapter.MyAdapterAdapterTest.submitGIApplicationToBDSExceptionTest(MyAdapterAdapterTest.java:15)